# Could not load file or assembly 'App_global.asax' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net

I updated one of my projects by adding a `.aspx` file. everything works fine on local machine and test server. When I publish the application to live, I am getting an error saying

> Could not load file or assembly 'App_global.asax' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I'm using `.NET 4.0` and my target framework is 4.0

Any help to get out of this issue greatly helps.

Comment: Check if your application pool framework version if 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the application pool of your live website is set to the correct dot net version, as in dot net 4 not dot net 2 which is what it sets it to by default.

Also make sure you have the correct dot net version installed on the server